Terminus Est and Le Croix; possible connection between Malzberg and Wolfe
I have come across a short story by Barry Malzberg called Terminus Est, and another called Le Croix. As a fan of Gene Wolfe, these names both are reminiscent of his work, as the weapon of pivotal importance to the protagonist of the Book of the New Sun is called Terminus Est, and Le Croix is the name of a planet colonized by French Terrans in Wolfe's Novella The Fifth Head of Cerberus.
I understand that the phrase "Terminus Est" simply means "The End" or something like that, and that "Le Croix" is "The Cross", so it may be nothing more in either instance than a reference to the Roman Catholic religion, nevertheless, I find the specific use of these memorable terms by both of these authors noticeable.
Does anyone have any insight or theories as to how one of them did or may have influenced the other?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is it really "le croix" (as opposed to the correct "la croix")?  It does seem odd they would both make the same error.

Severian says the sword's name means "the line of division" IIRC.

I'm not sure you can allege influence on the basis of a single word. Maybe they were both influenced by Asimov, who used Terminus as the name of a planet. As for "est" that's just Latin for "is" so I don't think you can make too much of that.

Actually, I think it's Sainte Croix in Fifth Head. A quick Google search shows that places on real-life earth are also called that, but I don't understand it. "Saint Cross"? Isn't "saint" an honorific for a person and not an artifact? Maybe it's equivalent to "Holy Cross"

Dunno why English has both saint and holy; it's the same thing in various languages.

@Mithoron English has two words for many things, e.g., there is also "kingly" and "royal", because it it a conglomerate of several languages, a germanic and a romance one.
